# In a GLM with interactive effects, what is the difference between ":" and "*"?

Tags: r, glm

If I'm trying to check interactive effects between factors in a linear model, what is the difference between
 `M1 <- glm(Capture ~ Season * Habitat , data=d)` and  `M1 <- glm(Capture ~ Season : Habitat , data=d)`?

I would like to check wether Captures are influenced by Season or Habitat or an interaction between both. What is the correct way of indicating an interaction between them in a linear model? Do I use ":" or "*" between facors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*` includes the interaction and the individual terms, whereas `:` includes just the interaction, ie `a * b` is short for `a + a:b + b`.

The correct way depends on whether or not you want the individual terms. From what i hear, in linear models, you often do. Also "check whether Captures are influenced by Season or Habitat or an interaction between both" looks like a job for `*`.